# Write text in OpenLayers3

Tags: openlayers-3

I need to write some text in openLayers 3... Not a label, something like a text object, that I can select and drag around the map. This text must have multiple lines.
I tried to use a point with ol.style.text, but it isn't multiline.
I also tried the popups, but I need the text to be always displayed.
Is there any way to use a text feature for this ([ol.format.TextFeature](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.format.TextFeature.html))?
Is there any object that I can use for that purpose?
Thanks!!

Comment: I'd use `ol.Overlay` tied to a `div` with the text. I'll make an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `ol.Overlay` for that.  An overlay is basically anything an `Element` can be.  It has a position an positioning that can be set at any time.

See an example: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/examples/overlay.html?q=overlay

You could use map browser events (pointerdown, pointerup) and if the target is your overlay element then you could move it around and update its position.

Comment: I also tried that and it's a possible solution. My only concern is the performance, because I may need to add a lot of those text elements. But maybe that's the only way. Thanks, Alexandre!

Comment: An addition you could do: if your data would have some sort of `priority` property, you could display only certain text at certain scales depending on the priority.  As you zoom in, more could appear.  That could make sure that not too many elements are shown at small scales and would also prevent too many overlapping text.  How does that sound ?